# How CPU simulator figures out the end of the program?

Tags: assembly, simulator, riscv, bare-metal, riscv32

I'm pretty new to RISC-V and I need your help.

I'm writing a simple RISC-V ISA simulator for RV32I architecture for a bare-metal environment. I know that we can get the entry point(the start of the program) in the elf file, but there is no information about the end of the program.

I saw the assembly code of exit() function which is come in the following.

```
00010548 <_exit>:
   10548:   05d00893            li  a7,93
   1054c:   00000073            ecall
   10550:   00054463            bltz    a0,10558 <_exit+0x10>
   10554:   0000006f            j   10554 <_exit+0xc>
   10558:   ff010113            addi    sp,sp,-16
   1055c:   00812423            sw  s0,8(sp)
   10560:   00050413            mv  s0,a0
   10564:   00112623            sw  ra,12(sp)
   10568:   40800433            neg s0,s0
   1056c:   00c000ef            jal ra,10578 <__errno>
   10570:   00852023            sw  s0,0(a0)
   10574:   0000006f            j   10574 <_exit+0x2c>
```

When the program reaches the exit() function the CPU will be stuck in an infinite loop(jump to itself), in this case, what should the CPU do? How should deal with such a jump instruction and how should figure out that this is the end of the program?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have a bare-metal single-task (I assume) environment, what should "end of program" mean? Do nothing, forever? Jump to self does that fine. Or return control to ??? (where?).

Comment: If you're simulating a CPU, a jump-to-self instruction should be easily detectable. You can then do whatever you like.

Comment: Some simulators provide a HALT instruction.  But I've mostly seen that for toy ISAs like LC3.  MARS detects your program dropping off the end of the instructions entered in the IDE, if you didn't make an exit syscall.  (I forget what SPIM does; it might just let your program fault if execution hits goes out of bounds of defined regions of memory.  In MIPS, the all-zero bit-pattern is a valid nop, although I think RISC-V is different.)

Comment: @dratenik Yes, true. it means to do nothing forever. so how should manage this infinite loop?

Comment: An embedded device (e.g. in an electric motor, solar inverter, washing machine) generally does its job forever, as long as power is applied. The concept of an "end of a program" simply doesn't make sense. There are a few exceptions such as critical errors or firmware update which usually cause a reboot (or an infinite loop).

Comment: In RISC-V the all zero pattern is an illegal instruction.  However, the RARS simulator (based on MARS) will issue the same message "... (dropped off bottom)".  Rather than issue the illegal instruction.  QtSpim says "Attempt to execute non-instruction" rather than execute `nop`s.  These simulators know where code is loaded and where it isn't, and in that regard do not behave like normal processors.

Comment: you would normally not want to use an infinite loop as you might find those normally as in the case above where there are two.  the ecall may do it or the store it is doing could also do it.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the RISC-V "wfi" instruction (wait for interrupt), which halts the CPU until a vlaid IRQ occurs.